# Field imageRepository in ImageService required a bean of type ImageRepository' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm working on a multi-module spring project and getting the following error:

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field imageRepository in com.example.service.ImageService required a bean of type 'com.example.repository.IImageRepository' that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.secureline.repository.IImageRepository' in your configuration.

Before using modules i didnt have this issue. The exports and requires in the module-info.java check out and everything is recognized within the IDE itself.

When running the Spring application it gives the error mentioned

resides in module "view" and has the main method that starts the spring project
application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "com.example.dto",
        "com.example.logger",
        "com.example.model",
        "com.example.repository",
        "com.example.security",
        "com.example.service"
})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

resides in module named "service"

ImageService (left out the service logic as it's not of importance for the question)

```
@Service("imageService")
public class ImageService implements IImageService {

    @Autowired
    private IImageRepository imageRepository;


    @Override
    public Image getById(Long id) {
        Optional<Image> result = imageRepository.findById(id);
        return result.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Image not found for id: " + id));
    }

    @Override
    public List<Image> getAll() {
        return imageRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Image image, Long performingUser) {
        imageRepository.delete(image);
    }

    @Override
    public Image save(Image image) {
        return imageRepository.save(image);
    }

    @Override
    public Image update(Image image, Long performingUser) throws AccessDeniedException {
        return imageRepository.save(image);
    }
}
```

Resides in module named "repository" in package com.example.repository;
IImagineRepository:

```
@Repository(value = "imageRepository")
public interface IImageRepository extends JpaRepository<Image, Long> {
}
```

I'm kind of clueless where this issue is located at so i'd highly appreciate any help!

Comment: You need to add @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.example.repository") in your main application class.

Comment: Place your `Application` class in the `com.example` package and ditch the `@ComponentScan` and other annotations, only leave the `@SpringBootApplication` class.

Comment: @M.Deinum i removed it out of the controllers package as it indeed did not belong there

Comment: If you moved it to the `com.example` package (the toplevel one) you don't need the annotations, just the `@SpringBootApplication`. This is also the recommended structure from the Spring Boot team (and is documented as such as well).